# vim - How do you save line numbers so you can easily jump to them whenever you want?

Tags: vim

Suppose I am working on three functions and I will be jumping back and forth between them. Suppose functions A,B, and C are on lines a, b and c. Is there a way to bind the following (which jump to the line position)

```
:a  
:b
:c
```

to keys during runtime so I can easily jump to these positions. If you play Starcraft this is kind of like binding a selected group of units to your number keys, and then using the number keys to quickly change your selected group (or jump to the designated line, in this case).

Or is there another way of getting a similar result that I am unaware of? I just recently discovered that =% autoformats your tabs within the highlighted brace, so I am pretty new to vim.

Thanks.

Comment: Vim as Starcraft.  Things will never be the same.

Comment: with vim, not only can you jump to a line quickly, but also a specific position. e.g. the 5th line, 9th word. just set a mark. I am not a starcraft fan. but I think if you can play it in vim way, you would be champion!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use [marks](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks).  They allow you to save your current position in the file to a variable.

Comment: As you say, you're new at Vim, so I should mention that the best way to find out more about something – for example, marks – is to use the built-in help.  In this case, try `:help marks` or `:help mark-motions`.

Answer (score 2):

In Starcraft, you "Hotkey" your guys by pressing Ctrl+1 to tag them, then tap 1 to select them again.
In Vim, you "Mark" a place by pressing [m], then [a](or any letter) to mark them, then [`], then [a] to go back to that mark.

So you have hotkeys to 1,2,3,4, etc in SC, but marks are a-z(and probably other characters but I'm not sure) in Vim.

For more technical info try

```
:help marks
```